# Yii2 Basic можно ли для модуля использовать модели не из этого модуля?

Tags: yii2, mvc, модули

у меня есть модель Order которая используется и на фронте приложения(просто в папке моделей) и в модуле Админ мне тоже нужна эта модель. Нужно ли создавать такую же модель только для модуля? Ведь модуль может работать отдельно он другой части приложения
P.S задавал этот вопрос раннее мнения расходятся

Comment: Если вы уже задавали этот вопрос ранее, то не стоит задавать его повторно.

Comment: не на этом форуме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует несколько разных подходов к построению архитектуры. По более правильным, академическим подходам (которыми на практике мало кто пользуется) вы должны держать одну модель Order и множество dto (ну вот в данном конкретном случае - одну для паблика, одну для crud-админки).

Однако из-за особенностей crud-приложений - в них (из-за отсутствия дополнительной бизнес-логики) классы dto практически всегда совпадают с основной моделью.

Оттого подход с анемичными моделями так популярен и найдётся много сторонников такого способа разработки.

Ведь никто не хочет делать лишнюю работу, а создание лишних слоёв абстракций - это самая что ни на есть зряшная работа: мало того, что на неё потратится время при разработке, так ещё потом на чтение кода, на поддержку.

Я как-то уже [приводил пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/887057/213987) (как раз на Order) когда у меня было три разных модели в админке: на создание сущности Order (без поля ID), на редактирование сущности Order (с полем ID) и на клонирование существующего Order (где был ID, но были не все поля, а только те, которые при клонировании по правилам проекта было разрешено менять). При этом это были именно view model'и, а model была одна - Order.

Строя архитектуру мы исходим из прогноза "нам нужно заложить здесь гибкость, так как приложение с высокой вероятностью будет расширяться в эту сторону". Если у вас на проекте один программист, а не две независимые команды, одна над админкой, одна над пабликом -- то вы просто зря потратите ресурсы на то, чтобы создать гибкость, которая никогда не "выстрелит". И когда ваш проект перейдёт к другому программисту -- будьте уверены, что он скажет много неласковых слов, когда для какого-то изменения в Order ему потребуется сделать изменения дважды. Сначала в одной модели, потом в другой. И если он забудет про вторую модель то ещё не раз вспомнит за поиском ошибки, затянувшейся на несколько часов. Так что хороший архитектор имеет хорошую чуйку в понимании, где надо предусматривать такие решения "на вырост", а где они нафиг не сдались.

Хотите рецепт для вашего конкретного проекта? Побуду немного астрологом: делайте одну модель.